# Tracking Sales Conversions Through Google Analytics's From My Site To Udemy.com

Tags: php, google-analytics

[Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer/learn/?couponCode=50%25OFFLIMITED) is one of the worlds leading online training websites with over 6 millions users. You can make your own courses on any subject and give it away for free or sell it.

I have my own [personal site](http://www.jacktrowbridge.co.uk/6-steps-to-becoming-an-elite-internet-marketer/) which is a landing page for my Udemy course where I collect the users emails and give them free content on a second page before they click a button to head over to Udemy to buy my course.

When a user opts into my landing page I assign a unique ID to there email. As well as information from a referral id / referrer telling me where the link was clicked which is just took from the URL as a GET HTTP variable.

I can then give someone or start a traffic source with my link which has a referral id and can link that user once they sign up with this id to see the percentage of users to viewing my landing page to opting in from a given referrer id or link.

Through Google Analytics's I can also monitor all the pages on my Udemy account by giving them my Google Analytics's ID after setting up a site in the Analytics's dashboard for my Udemy course.

I've setup a site within Analytics's for my landing page / personal website as well as Udemy. I want to track the conversions of visitors going from my landing page to purchasing the course on Udemy.

Is this possible?

To summarize I can track them both independently its just linking my personal website with Udemy so I can see which user went onto my site has bought a course on Udemy. If I could store there unique ID at the point of sale somewhere? Google Analytics's ?

Without this then I don't know which referral ID / referrer from a particular traffic source converted the most into sales!

Answer (score -1):

Build a Thank You Landing Page after the Course Purchasing Page then put google tracking code in the Thank You Landing Page. So whenever anyone land on Thank You page after purchasing your course then Google will track that and tell you that he/she has purchased your course.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).